# WHy Data given not inserted into Mongoose DB

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mongoose, jestjs

I am writing test cases to cover unit test for each feature file using the jest technique I ended up with success ran but not data is not inserting into DB [image]

Structure[image] :

user.js //this is where i am intorducing user schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// schema 
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    gender: { type: String, required: true},
    dob: Date,
    loginUsing: String,
});

const userModel = new mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = userModel
```

user.test.js //this is my file where I writing test cases.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserModel = require('./user');
const userData = { name: 'tim', gender: 'Female', dob: new Date(), loginUsing: 'Twitter' };

describe('User Model Test', () => {

    // It's just so easy to connect to the MongoDB Memory Server 
    // By using mongoose.connect
    beforeAll(async() => {
        await mongoose.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                process.exit(1);
            }
        });
    });

    it('create & save user successfully', async() => {
        const validUser = new UserModel(userData);
        const savedUser = await validUser.save();
        // Object Id should be defined when successfully saved to MongoDB.
        expect(savedUser._id).toBeDefined();
        expect(savedUser.name).toBe(userData.name);
        expect(savedUser.gender).toBe(userData.gender);
        expect(savedUser.dob).toBe(userData.dob);
        expect(savedUser.loginUsing).toBe(userData.loginUsing);
    });

    afterAll(async() => {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    });
})
```

server.js //this is my server file

```
// Import config from .env file
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// Init MongoDB Connection
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', () => {
    console.error('Error Connection to MongoDB')
});
db.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});
mongoose.connect(process.env.mongodb_uri, {useNewUrlParser: true});


app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Unit Test MongoDB with Jest app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

.env.dist //in this file where i have declared my mongoose uri connection

```
# MongoDB Connection String
mongodb_uri=****** //replaced with my mongoose DB connection
```